# Is the term callback bound to asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, computer-science, terminology

I am going through `asynchronous` posts and find that the term `callback` is always used with `asynchronous`, so my question is

1. Is the term `callback` bound to `asynchronous`?
2. Does `callback` have other meanings in computer science?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback is a function that is passed to a library function that the library uses to notify the application of completed task.

In my experience, most "callbacks" are synchronous.

Some operating system have asynchronous callbacks but these are generally called things like "asynchronous system traps" or "asynchronous procedure calls."